# How to add transition animation to all actions in Jetpack Navigation?

Tags: android, android-transitions, android-architecture-navigation, android-jetpack-navigation

To add transition animation in Jetpack navigation, we can add animation attributes to action like below in xml

```
<action
    android:id="@+id/action_fragment1_to_fragment2"
    app:destination="@id/fragment2"
    app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_in_right"
    app:exitAnim="@anim/slide_out_left"
    app:popEnterAnim="@anim/slide_in_left"
    app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_out_right"/>
```

To make it pragmatically

```
NavOptions navOptions = new NavOptions.Builder()
   .setEnterAnim(R.anim.slide_in_right)
   .setExitAnim(R.anim.slide_out_left)
   .setPopEnterAnim(R.anim.slide_in_left)
   .setPopExitAnim(R.anim.slide_out_right)
   .build();
```

But in my case I have so many fragments in the project and it would be a tedious task to define animation over every single actions,

**Is there anyway we can define animation for every action at once and it will apply transition animation to every actions?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Reuse your `navOptions` by a custom util class

Comment: Thanks @huang12345 but again it would required to modify every `navigate()` implementation

Comment: You can change default behaviour of R.anim class

Comment: Can you help with a sample? @jigarkanjariya

Comment: Create a NavHostController subclass whose navigate method uses your NavOptions by default.

Comment: @AlexMandelias I know it's late, I encountered this issue a few years back, and I have posted a simple solution in answer.

Comment: @Maddy I read through your solution. I noticed however that the question is in Java, and the answer is in Kotlin haha. I wanted to provide a solution which works in both languages.

Comment: @AlexMandelias Kotlin is interoperable, and will work with both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a few extension method to manage animation of each navigation actions.

```
fun NavController.safeNavigate(
    @IdRes direction: Int,
    popupTo: Int? = null,
    inclusive: Boolean = false,
    args: Bundle? = null,
    options: NavOptions = buildAnimOptions(popupTo, inclusive)
) {
    navigate(direction, args, options)
}

fun NavController.safeNavigate(
    navDirections: NavDirections,
    popupTo: Int? = null,
    inclusive: Boolean = false,
    options: NavOptions = buildAnimOptions(popupTo, inclusive)
) {
    navigate(navDirections, options)
}

private fun buildAnimOptions(
    popupTo: Int?,
    inclusive: Boolean = false
): NavOptions {
    val builder = NavOptions.Builder()
        .setEnterAnim(R.anim.right_in)
        .setExitAnim(R.anim.left_out)
        .setPopEnterAnim(R.anim.left_in)
        .setPopExitAnim(R.anim.right_out)
    if (popupTo != null) builder.setPopUpTo(popupTo, inclusive)
    return builder.build()
}
```